# How to move values around in a HashMap

Tags: java

I have class, lets say Hockey. The Hockey class will set the hockey's score like the code below:

```
public class Hockey{
  private HashMap<String, Integer> hockeyScore;

  public Hockey(){
    hockeyScore = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
  }

  public void setHockeyScore(String clubName, int score){
    hockeyScore.put(clubName, score);  
  }
}
```

A hockey game will only have two teams and two scores, is it possible to swap the scores?
For example when we insert into hashmap and it comes out with the keys and values...

> team 'a' = 23
>
> team 'b' = 10

then you swap the values in the hashmap which will look like...

> team 'a' = 10
>
> team 'b' = 23

Sorry guys, I was wondering if there is a like a method that swaps the scores around, without manually using the 'a' and 'b' reference. Like once you insert any keys and values into the hashmap, this method will swap the values around.

Comment: Use `String[2]` and `int[2]` and swap in the arrays.

Comment: It is a bit of overkill to use a HashMap for only two and exactly two entries. You can make a class, eg. ScoreResult, holding the name and the result, and either make two instances in two variables, or make an array of this class with two entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could swap `Map` entries using this one-liner:

```
hockeyScore.put(a, hockeyScore.put(b, hockeyScore.get(a)));
```

Answer (score 6):

Sure, the way you traditionally swap values:

```
Integer tmp = map.get(a);
map.put(a, map.get(b));
map.put(b, tmp);
```

Comment: Oh yeah, it's totally impossible to do atomically, even with a full `concurrentMap`.

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble imagining why you would want to do this, but it is only possible in the case of a Map with 2 entries--otherwise, swap is meaningless.

My Java is a bit rusty, and I am not going to pull out Eclipse just to check syntax but something quite similar to this should do the job for you:

```
Map<string, int> swapped(string key1, string key2, Map<string, int> m) {
    Map dummy = new HashMap<string, int>();

    dummy.put(key2, m.get(key1));
    dummy.put(key1, m.get(key2));

    return dummy;
}
```

If you are more ambitious, you could iterate the entries to get the keys rather than having to have them available.

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer aScore = hockeyScore.get("a");
hockeyScore.put("a", map.get("b"));
hockeyScore.put("b", aScore);
```

and the threadsafe variant

```
synchronized (hockeyScore) {
   Integer aScore = hockeyScore.get("a");
   hockeyScore.put("a", map.get("b"));
   hockeyScore.put("b", aScore);
}
```

Comment: Still not threadsafe.  If people doing things besides swapping are modifying your map the lock will not be shared properly.  However this is somewhat debatable as it's not clear what the invariant that should be preferred under threadsafety is, but yes all kind of a digression, chances are OP does not have this concern now.

Comment: of course you will not publish the hockeyScore map (if you want it threadsafe)! all  access to the map must be synchronized, every read, every write!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help!

I have figured out away to swap the values in the hashmap. First I collected the scores and put them into an arraylist and then i compared the arraylist to the hashmap and re set the hash map according the the arraylist.

```
public void swapScores(){ 
        for(Map.Entry<Team, Integer> getScores: winningTeam.entrySet()){
            if(scores.get(0).equals(getScores.getValue())){
                getScores.setValue(scores.get(1));
                System.out.println(getScores.getKey().getTeamName()+":"+getScores.getValue());
            }else if(scores.get(1).equals(getScores.getValue())){
                getScores.setValue(scores.get(0));
                System.out.println(getScores.getKey().getTeamName()+":"+getScores.getValue());
            }
        }

    }
```

If there is a shorter way to do this please let me know.

Thank you again everyone!